# Cant add script behavior "Ilauncher". the script class cant be abstract

Tags: c#, unity3d

Создаю игру при помощи библиотеки tower defense template от unity. В документации сказано, что необходимо добавить на пустой объект скрипт `AttackingAgent` или `FlyingAgent`.

При добавлении любого из них появляется ошибка. Оба эти скрипта наследуются от абстрактного класса `Agent`. Убрать абстрактность у класса просто так не получается, так как в нём есть абстрактные методы, которые переписываются через `override` в скриптах `AttackingAgent` и `FlyingAgent`.

Скрипт Agent:

```
public abstract class Agent : Targetable

protected abstract void PathUpdate();

protected abstract void OnPartialPathUpdate();
```

Скрипт Flying Agent:

```
protected override void PathUpdate()

protected override void OnPartialPathUpdate()
```